# How to release a package with python-specific wheels to the GitLab Package Registry and twine

Tags: package, registry, gitlab-ci, python-wheel, twine

I try to use GitLab CI to automate the package release process and store the releases in GitLab Package Registry. I have followed the documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/

and managed to setup the CI so it builds and pushes wheels to the Package Registry.

However, I have faced an issue when there are several pipelines building different versions of the package, specific to different python  versions. When I have more than 1 version of wheel in a given release, it seems that the Package Registry index is not correctly matching the versions and only the last file (literally last, following the upload/push the order) uploaded to the registry is available/can be installed via pip.

Here's the setup - extension of the `mypypipackage` example from GitLab docs:

1. in my setup.py I am "baking" python into the wheel:

```
import sys
import setuptools

# Set the required version of python.
__python_version__ = "=={}.{}.*".format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor)

# Set python tag if building a wheel.
if "bdist_wheel" in sys.argv:
    if not any(arg.startswith('--python-tag') for arg in sys.argv):
        sys.argv.extend(['--python-tag', "py{}{}".format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor)])

setuptools.setup(
    name="mypypipackage",
    version="0.1.3",
    author="tkornuta",
    description="A small example package",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: {}.{}'.format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor),
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires=__python_version__,
)
```

2. I have set up the GitLab CI to build three wheels, for three different python versions/containers:

```
python36:
  image: "urm.nvidia.com/docker/python:3.6"
  script:
    - python -c "import sys; print('{}.{}.*'.format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor))"
    - pip install twine
    - python setup.py bdist_wheel
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --repository-url  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi dist/*

python37:
  image: "urm.nvidia.com/docker/python:3.7"
  script:
    - python -c "import sys; print('{}.{}.*'.format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor))"
    - pip install twine
    - python setup.py bdist_wheel
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --repository-url  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi dist/*

python38:
  image: "urm.nvidia.com/docker/python:3.8"
  script:
    - python -c "import sys; print('{}.{}.*'.format(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor))"
    - pip install twine
    - python setup.py bdist_wheel
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --repository-url  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi dist/*
```

3. When Ci completes, I can clearly see three versions of the wheel in Package Registry for this release (0.1.3):

[image]

4. When installing "the latest uploaded" wheel (i.e. for python 3.8) file it works correctly:

```
(p38) tkornuta@aaa:~$ pip install mypypipackage --index-url https://<personal_access_token_name>:<personal_access_token>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
Looking in indexes: https://<personal_access_token_name>:****@@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
Collecting mypypipackage
  Downloading https://bbb/mypypipackage-0.1.3-py38-none-any.whl (1.6 kB)
Installing collected packages: mypypipackage
Successfully installed mypypipackage-0.1.3
```

5. But when I try to install wheel with a different python version, e.g. in venv with python 3.7, pip throws an error:

```
(p37) tkornuta@aaa$ pip install mypypipackage==0.1.3 --index-url https://<personal_access_token_name>:<personal_access_token>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
Looking in indexes: https://<personal_access_token_name>:****@@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypypipackage==0.1.3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mypypipackage==0.1.3
```

I have managed to successfully download and manually install the wheels for both python 3.6 and 3.7 versions - no problems here. I have also did some experiments and uploaded e.g. only one wheel for 3.7 - and managed to install it via pip straight from the Package Registry without any problems.

So what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Is this a problem with Package Registry that it cannot handle/serve many versions of a given wheel for a given release?

Thanks,
Tomasz

Ps.
I have asked this question also on [gitlab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/problem-with-releasing-python-specific-wheels-to-package-registry/50704), hope in here I can reach a broader audience, maybe someone figured it out how to solve this issue.